# Does Spring-Data-JDBC support Oracle identity columns?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to save into a table with an Oracle identity field (it's some sort of auto increment). But as soon as I do that I get an "identity must not be null after save" exception ?

Is this scenario currently not supported or do I need a special config ?

BTW: it's works with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. 
Spring Data JDBC currently does not identity fields with Oracle Databases.